# interior of union of two sets

Tags: general-topology

I have been reading about some properties of interior and closure operator.

I came across the fact that For any topological space $X$ and $A$ and $B$ $\subseteq X$.It is not true in general $i(A \cup B )=i(A) \cup i(B)$
.We have the counter example as the set $A=[0,1] \cup (1,2) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

But I would be interseted in knowing that can we impose any condition on $A$ and $B$ in general topological space so that equality holds.Will it hold if the two sets are disjoint??

Comment: $[0,1]$ and $(1,2)$ actually are disjoint, so that's not a sufficient condition. I'm not well-versed in Topology, but I believe that if $A$ and $B$ are separated then equality should hold

Comment: Being disjoin is not sufficient. The boundaries must also be disjoint.

Comment: @MichaelBlakeman you are correct my example only rules out my intuition that the sets being disjoint imply that the equality holds.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Do you mean if $b$ denotes the boundary then $b(A \cap B)=\phi$ is sufficient condition to show that the equality holds?

Comment: I mean that if $\partial(A) \cap \partial(B)$ is null, then the equality holds.

Comment: @BalarkaSen means since one way containment always holds.So we are required to prove $i(A \cup B) \subseteq i(A) \cup i(B) \iff b(A) \cap b(B) =\phi$ where $i$ is interior operator and $b$ is boundary operator.Correct?

Comment: Sure, @User23. ${}$

Comment: @BalarkaSen I will try to prove it if i can..

Comment: @BalarkaSen please show me the direction to proceed.I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset=A\cap\overline{B}$.

If $x\in\text{int}\left(A\cup B\right)$
and $x\in A$ then also $x\in\text{int}\left(A\cup B\right)\cap\overline{B}^{c}\subseteq A$.

Note that $\text{int}\left(A\cup B\right)\cap\overline{B}^{c}$ is
open so we are allowed to conclude that $x\in\text{int}\left(A\right)$.

If $x\in\text{int}\left(A\cup B\right)$
and $x\in B$ then likewise we find $x\in\text{int}\left(B\right)$

Proved is now that $\text{int}\left(A\cup B\right)\subseteq\text{int}A\cup\text{int}B$
and it is obvious that also $\text{int}A\cup\text{int}B\subseteq\text{int}\left(A\cup B\right)$.

Comment: so you mean to say we got a  condition $i(A \cup B)=i(A) \cup i(B) \iff \overline{A} \cap B = \phi$ or $A \cap \overline{B} = \phi$?

Comment: In my answer I am only saying that $\Leftarrow$ is true here. I haven't examined the converse yet.

Comment: got your point.

Comment: Btw, the converse is not true. E.g. take $A=B\neq\emptyset$. Then $i(A\cup B)=i(A)=i(B)=i(A)\cup i(B)$, but $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$

Comment: I have one query in the proof you provided above Since $A \cap \overline{B} = \phi$ implies that $\overline{B} \subseteq A^c$ means $A \subseteq \overline{B}^c$.But you have used the other way containment...I may be getting it totally wrong..Please elaborate??

Comment: If $x\in i(A\cup B)$ then we discern two possibilities: $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. In the first case we conclude that $x\in\overline B^c$ (using $A\subseteq\overline B^c$)

Comment: thats my point you are concluding $x \in int(A)$ by the help of the fact that $(A \cup B)\cap \overline{B}^c$ is an open subset of $A$ containing $x$ and $intA$ is the largest open subset of $A$ but to conclude $(A \cup B)\cap \overline{B}^c$  to be an subset of $A$ we need $\overline{B}^c  \subseteq A$ but it holds that $A \subseteq \overline{B}^c$

Comment: $i(A\cup B)\cap\overline{B}^{c}\subseteq(A\cup B)\cap\overline{B}^{c}=(A\cap\overline{B}^{c})\cup(B\cap\overline{B}^{c})=A\cup\varnothing=A$.
Here $A\cap\overline{B}^{c}=A$ because $A\subseteq\overline{B}^{c}$.
I don't use $\overline{B}^{c}\subseteq A$ anywhere.