# Show that $Int((\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (\overline{B}\setminus B))=\emptyset$ for two open subsets $A,B$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ a topological space. Show that if $A,B\in \tau$ then $$Int((\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (\overline{B}\setminus B))=\emptyset$$

Comment: Have you tried anything? Moreover, why are you considering two sets $A$ and $B$? Is it true for a single set $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that $"Int"$ distributes in finite unions and finite intersections, and $\overline{A}= A\cup Fr\{A\}$. So
\begin{align*}
Int((\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (\overline{B}\setminus B))= \hspace{0.1cm}&
Int(\overline{A}\setminus A) \cup Int(\overline{B}\setminus B)\\ =\hspace{0.1cm} &Int((A\cup Fr\{A\})\cap A^{c}) \cup Int((B\cup Fr\{B\})\cap B^{c})
\end{align*}

Since $A$ and $B$ are open, $Int(Fr\{A\}) = Int(Fr\{B\}) = \emptyset$ (why?). Then

\begin{align*}
Int((\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (\overline{B}\setminus B))= \hspace{0.1cm}&
(Int(A)\cap Int(A^{c})) \cup (Int(B)\cap Int(B^{c})) \\ =\hspace{0.1cm} &
\emptyset \cup \emptyset \\ =\hspace{0.1cm} & \emptyset
\end{align*}

Comment: It is not true in general that $Int $ is distributive. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068915/interior-of-union-of-two-sets

Comment: @rt6 ... before  I showed that $Int((\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (\overline{B}\setminus B))=Int(\rm{Fr}(A)\cup\rm{Fr}(B))$ but I can't finish the exercise